# Ggplot x and y axis scalling

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am totally new R and i have a trouble with ggplot(). I want scale the x and y axis values in the plot. As you can see in picture, x and y axis are showing each and every point for plot which makes graph less readable:

[image].

How can i scale the x and y axes?

The code i used to plot is:

```
ggplot(final, aes(timeAtServer, timestamp, color = name)) +  geom_point()
```

I also tried

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(final$timestamp), max(), by = 0.5),1))
```

for break points but the result was same.

Comment: the problem is that your data is `factor` class, not some sort of time class (which is what you want

Comment: Usually this sort of thing happens because the columns in the data frame you are plotting are not in the format you think they are. As noted above, they are probably factors, and you probably want to convert them to some sort of time class like POSIXct or something.

Comment: so can i convert it into some time class(integer)??How should it be done?? just change covert the type of the column ??

Comment: to change the data class you'll need to reassign it using the as.POSIXct command like: df$colname<-as.POSIXct(df$colname). its hard to know exactly how without seeing how the data is formated

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for your help...should i post the data?...

TimeAtServer is  unix timestamp values and timestamp is rolling timestamp counter between 0 to 999999999..(ie 1 sec)..

@Tom i got an error like this
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(as.character(x), ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: @SeñorO Thanks a lot for your information too

Comment: Start reading `?strptime`, carefully.

Comment: @joran got it...First i need to covert factor into character then into posix...

Thanks for your help to all..

Could someone close it by answering??